# Get color palette from R to python plots

Tags: python, r, plot, seaborn

I'm working on some plots in python, and so far the closest result to R like plots I have found with a standard library is using seaborn.

For Example for an ROC plot, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

sns.set()


target = testy
legends = ['test']
colors=['black']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for value, prob, legend, c in list(zip([target], [probs], legends, colors)):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(value, prob)
    msg = 'roc_curve for : {} calculated'.format(legend)
    logging.info(msg)
    auc_test = roc_auc_score(value, prob)
    ax.plot(fpr * 100, tpr * 100, marker='.', label=legend + ' %.2f' % auc_test, color=c)
    ax.plot([0, 100], [0, 100], color='darkblue', linestyle='--')
    ax.set_title('ROC Curve', fontweight='bold', loc='left')
    ax.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate', fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate', fontweight='bold')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter())

ax.legend(loc=5)
```

which produces a plot like:

[image]

Which is still far from been like a R plot:

[image]

R plot looks much more cleaner, and also seaborn have some black dots that I would like to hide:

[image]

Comment: Remove  `import seaborn as sns` and `sns.set`. To get rid of the markers, remove `marker='.',`

Comment: Seaborn has themes and aesthetics you can change, have you tried doing any of that? https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html

Comment: @camille yes I did, not good results